# Excel: check if two cells have specific content and show true/false in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a large datasheet with multiple columns. Long story short, my columns A and B (of text type) are lists of codes. For simplicity's sake let's say column A is days of the week, while column B is a list of chores. Some codes cannot occur together – i.e. "Monday" can never go with "cleaning" and "Wednesday" can never go with "vaccuming".

What I would like to achieve is that next to each of my pairs of cells An and Bn there is a Cn cell that displays TRUE/FALSE information should any of the forbidden combinations occur.

I don't want to check if the content of cells is matching.

How do I achieve that? My formula-making skills are mediocre at best, unfortunately – counting the occurences of a code within a column is the peak of my competence.

Comment: Intersting question. The way around this is you need to have a list of no no's, such as Monday and Cleaning. You will then probably use a VLOOKUP to check the values of this other list. Or, do it with VBa, but it will essentially be the same approach

Comment: How many pieces of criteria do you have? Your post suggests only 2 (Monday/Cleaning and Wednesday/Vaccuming)

Comment: I have about 4-5 pairs that cannot occur together, but I have way more possible contents than I indicated in the example. I'd prefer a formula-based approach, however, as I am time pressed and all my uses of VBA were limited to copy-paste and pressing F5 ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list of A's and a list of B's. You have some (A,B) combinations that are false, the rest are true.

Create a **new** list of the forbidden combinations, then add another column that concatenates the combinations that you don't allow like "MondayCleaning", "WednesdayVacuuming" etc. To concatenate strings use this formula:

```
=A1&B1
```

To make adding new combinations easier later either make the range larger that you initially need or better create a named range (lets say we call it **Forbidden**).

In your original column C you will now look up the concatenation of A & B to see if it is in your new list of forbidden combinations. If it is then it will return the position in this list. If not then it will return #N/A. So your final formula for returning TRUE if the combination is ok and FALSE otherwise is:

```
=ISERROR(MATCH(An&Bn,Forbidden,0))
```

Let me know if this is useful, perhaps I can attach a google sheet?

Edit: Here's a [link to an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pQbs8Qj1hizzzBUme7jCl8Y2fsFVlVIpdOMu84zCUoM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to do that with static concatenations? Since I only have 4-5 of them, it would seem simpler.

Comment: Even though I successfully applied another solution, yours looks like it might come in handy with another sets of data I will have to work with. An example sheet would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Added a link in the answer

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
=OR(AND(A1="Mon",B1="Clean"),AND(A1="Wed",B1="Vacc"))
```

and you can add other conditions as AND. This command gives `TRUE` if one of this condition is meet. So if `TRUE` and unregular combination is done

Comment: I don't like this solutions - whilst it *will* work, the formula length could easily become huge and maintaining this would become pretty yucky! If OP only has a couple of criteria, then it's a great solution (and the OP has only given 1 example so may be it's the answer)!

Comment: @Dave I know but since is an easy solution without any macro or VB programming i think the OP will be glad :)

Comment: Thanks! While this looks just like what I need (indeed, 3-4 conditions), the formula does not work – Excel 2007 says it contains an error. I tried to put that in =IF(…), but the result remains the same :(

Comment: no `if` needed just go with this formula on a new column. http://1drv.ms/1Lnqc1T

Comment: OK, I got it to work – turns out Polish Office uses semicolons in place of commas (for whatever reason)… Works like charm, thank you!